# How can I save variables with value type Measurement<UnitType> using Realm Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, realm, persistence

Does `Realm Swift` support saving and retrieving data with value type `Measurement`? Here is the class structure of the data I'm trying to save:

```
class Race: Object {
@objc dynamic var raceDistance: Measurement<UnitLength>?
@objc dynamic var nettTime = Measurement<UnitDuration>?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Measurement`s themselves are not supported by Realm, but they conform to `Codable`, so you can save an encoded version of them:

```
@objc dynamic var encodedRaceDistance: Data?
// Realm 10.10+
// @Persisted var encodedRaceDistance: Data?
```

And you can add a computed property like this to get the `Measurement<UnitLength>` from the data:

```
var raceDistanceMeasurement: Measurement<UnitLength>? {
    get {
        if let encoded = encodedRaceDistance {
            return try? JSONDecoder().decode(Measurement<UnitLength>.self, from: encoded)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            encodedRaceDistance = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
        } else {
            encodedRaceDistance = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Restoring a UnitLength like this does not work as I expect. Trying to convert it returns 0. Am I missing something?

`var test = Measurement(value: 23, unit: UnitLength(symbol: "mm"))`
`test.convert(to: UnitLength(symbol: "cm"))`

It appears I can enter any string at all for the symbol.

Comment: This, on the other hand, works as expected... `var test = Measurement(value: 23, unit: UnitLength.millimeters)
test.convert(to: UnitLength.centimeters)`

Comment: @Mathieson Hmm, me 3 years ago clearly did not know a lot :D `Measurement` conforms to `Codable`, so storing `Data` then encoding and decoding with `JSONDecoder` should work?

Comment: Ah! That's a good thought. I might not need to persist the type of Unit any longer, but if I find the need to again, I will dig further into that thought!

Comment: I haven't had the need to get back to this yet, but my need for recreating a Measurement was for CoreData rather than Realm. In researching other CoreData stuff, I just came across this article, which seems highly relevant: avanderlee.com/swift/valuetransformer-core-data/